# using JGAp (genetic algorithm library) and the duplicated chromosomes

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, jgap

I used the JGAp java genetic algorithm library.
and when I evaluated the chromosomes , I had duplication of chromosomes in the population
sample run :

```
evaluation 0
A B C
A D F
S F W
evaluation 1:
A B C
A D F
A D F
evaluation 2:
A D F
A D F
A D F
```

and the configurations I have used are:

```
conf.setKeepPopulationSizeConstant(true);
 conf.setRandomGenerator(new StockRandomGenerator());
conf.verifyStateIsValid();
```

is there any configuration that I can used in order to get unique chromosomes?

Comment: What genetic operators do you use? Could it be that the population size is too small combined with conservative genetic operators and a fitness function that quickly identified the fittest individual and reproduced that one (without mutation or combinations)?

Comment: I used Swapping operater using this Configurations conf.getGeneticOperators().clear();
MutationOperator swapper = new SwappingMutationOperator(conf);
conf.addGeneticOperator(swapper);   and I try to make population size 500 the same problem is there! any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure only to use [NaturalSelectors](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/javadoc/2.0/org/jgap/NaturalSelector.html) that does not allow duplicates. Example code:

```
conf.getNaturalSelectors(false).clear();
BestChromosomesSelector bcs = new BestChromosomesSelector(conf, 1.0d);
bcs.setDoubletteChromosomesAllowed(false);
conf.addNaturalSelector(bcs, false);
```

Please note that only using SwappingMutationOperator will probably starve the ingenuity of the population. A test modifying the MinimizingMakeChange example from JGAP, but using only the SwappingMutationOperator, shows that the population quickly stops producing individuals that have not been seen before.

Comment: yes it works :) thank you so much for your replay. I used your configurations and delete the Swapping operator and it's work exactly like what I want. thanks a lot.