# Chromosome with non repeated alleles

Tags: jgap

I read a recommendation of how to find non-duplicated chromosomes:
[using JGAp (genetic algorithm library) and the duplicated chromosomes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473397/using-jgap-genetic-algorithm-library-and-the-duplicated-chromosomes)

How do you find a chromosome with non-repeated alleles using JGAP?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this problem recently too...

My current solution is simply to include a **large penalty** in the **fitness function** of my genetic algorithm, when the chromosome contains duplicate alleles.

Whilst I imagine there are better ways of approaching this problem, this seems to be working - for my purposes at least..